# Unit test a firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, firefox, jsunit

I'm working on a Firefox extension and started building automated tests using jsUnit. I run into permission errors running the tests from the TestRunner as soon as my extension code refers to any XPCom components.

Is there a better tool for me to use for this, or how I can get around the permissions issues and continue to use jsUnit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't started using it yet, but [UxU](http://www.clear-code.com/software/uxu/index.html.en) appears to be a really good tool for unit testing Firefox extensions. I don't know how well it can deal with XPCOM, but I believe it runs the tests from a context where it has the permissions it needs for that sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be what I'm looking for.